# Multi country validation rules

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations

In my multi country site, I have a form for address creation. I want customize my validation rules by country (For example : FR ZipCode length 8, USA : 10...), and I hesitate between many solution : one ViewModel by Country, Parameterized annotation, DataFilter... Any idea ?

```
public class Address
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [StringLength(lengthByCountry)]
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`CustomValidationAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.customvalidationattribute.aspx) to write your own validator that does country-specific validation of ZIP codes depending on the country.

Comment: with CustomValidationAttribute I have to manually doing client-side validation, right ?

Comment: @rad: The `CustomValidationAttribute` allows you to plug into the validation framework and write your own validator that does something else than checking a string length or uses a regular expression. That is "manual" work, yes, but you don't have to call the validation method in your code. Just as you don't have to call any string length checking when you use the `StringLengthAttribute`.

Answer (score 1):

If the country and zip code need to be specified within the same submission, then I'd suggest making your model implement IValidatableObject, which allows you to validate based on combinations of values.

```
public class Address : IValidatableObject
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Country { get; set; }

    public string ZipCode { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {

        var results = new List<ValidationResult>();

        switch (Country)
        {
            case "France":
                if (ZipCode.Length < 8)
                    results.Add(
                        new ValidationResult("French zip codes must be at least 8 characters", new List<string> { "ZipCode" })
                    );
                break;

            case "U.S.":
                if (ZipCode.Length < 10)
                    results.Add(
                        new ValidationResult("American zip codes must be at least 10 characters", new List<string> { "ZipCode" })
                    );
                break;

            // Etc.
        }

        return results;

    }

}
```

Comment: I really don't understand why almost everyone that suggests IValidateableObject failes to mention that it doesn't do client-side validation.  This is a perfectly acceptable solution in many cases, but people need to know that it can cause weirdness in their validation workflows.